# ggplotly tooltip with revealjs r markdown presentation

Tags: r, r-markdown, reveal.js, htmlwidgets

I'm using an rmarkdown `.Rmd` file to create a `revealjs_presentation`.

However, when I create a chart using `ggplotly`, the tooltip no longer lines up with the points when hovering.  Here is an example:

````
---
title: ""
output: 
  revealjs::revealjs_presentation:
    center: true
---


```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)
```

Plotly
------------------------------

```{r, echo=F, message=F}
(ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) + geom_point()) %>%
  ggplotly()
```
````

It doesn't do this with `output: html_document`.  At different zoom levels in the browser, the tooltip gets closer or further away from the point when the hover information appears.

Has anyone run into this?

Answer (score 4):

I was facing the same issue, here's what I found :

1. It's quite well documented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35973794/incorporate-leaflet-map-in-revealjs-presentation-within-r), [here](https://github.com/yihui/xaringan/issues/98) and [here](https://github.com/rstudio/revealjs/issues/47).
2. Workaraound : put the plot inside of a `widgetframe::frameWidget()`, see [here](https://github.com/yihui/xaringan/issues/98).
3. **Solution** : add the following reveal_options (see [here](https://github.com/ramnathv/htmlwidgets/issues/219#issuecomment-234048952)) :

```
reveal_options:
  minScale: 1.0
  maxScale: 1.0
```

Now everything *seems* to be working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

If this is helpful for anyone, this seems to be entirely related to zoom.

At 140% zoom in my browser all of the `htmlwidgets` that I'm using (`highcharter`, `plotly`) line up correctly between the tooltip and the point I'm hovering over.

Maybe depends on screen size and browser too.